# prevent jQuery post request executed twice by double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, post

I've searched for equal questions, but found not a single one for my specific case.

I have an element

```
<span id="myButton">Click</span>
```

and a jQuery post-request bound to it

```
$(document).ready( function()
      {
      $(document).on( 'click', '#myButton', function(e)
        {
        $.post( "RESPONDING_WEBPAGE_HERE.php" ).done( function( result )
            {
            console.log( result );
            });
        });
      });
```

Now, for every time you click the button, it makes a post-request. Makes sense. What I want is a good solution for only executing the post-request, if the result function (*.done()*) is executed.

For sure, I know to handle that with a variable like **var isAjaxRequest = false;** setting it to true, and back to false in the resulting function, but maybe there is a better (jQuery build-in) way of doing it.

Here is my solution by now. I would be really great if there are better ones.

```
var isAjaxRequest = false;    
$(document).ready( function()
          {
          $(document).on( 'click', '#myButton', function(e)
            {
            if( !isAjaxRequest )
              {
              isAjaxRequest = true;
              $.post( "RESPONDING_WEBPAGE_HERE.php" ).done( function( result )
                {
                isAjaxRequest = false;
                console.log( result );
                });
              }
            });
          });
```

Thank you =)

Comment: use .attr() to disable button after first click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to attach the event handler and re-attach the event after the ajax call is complete. This will handle all cases even when your target doesn't support disabling:

```
//define handler function
var myButtonHandler = function(e) {
  $.post("RESPONDING_WEBPAGE_HERE.php").done(function() {
    attachButtonHandler("#mybutton"); //re-attach the click event after AJAX complete
  });
}

//attach an event handler that's only good for one click
function attachButtonHandler(selector) {
  $(document).one('click', selector, myButtonHandler);
}

//on doc ready, attach the event handler for the first time
$(function() {
  attachButtonHandler("#mybutton");
});
```

Comment: Re-attaching handlers, after every call... isn't that time expensive or does javascript/jQuery only store a function-pointer inside core?

Comment: jQuery doesn't do any magic here and there is some overhead with re-attaching the event handlers, but I've used this a lot without ever encountering any performance problems. It all depends on volume--is your page going to be doing this hundreds of times per second? If not I doubt you'll notice any performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

I commonly set the button to disabled when it is clicked and then remove the disabled attribute on the callbacks for the POST request.

```
$(document).on('click', '#button', function () {
  $('#button').attr('disabled', true);

  $.post('something').done(function () {
    $('#button').removeAttr('disabled');
  }).fail(function () {
    $('#button').removeAttr('disabled');
  });
});
```

This will prevent the button from being clicked again once it has already been clicked.

As per the comments; If you want this behaviour on a span element or others which don't allow the disabled attribute, you could set a class when clicked.

```
$(document).on('click', 'span#button:not(.disabled)', function () {
  $(this).addClass('disabled');

  $.post('something').done(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('disabled');
  }).fail(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('disabled');
  });
});
```

The above code will make sure the element can only be clicked if it doesn't have the `disabled` class. This will also work for the button elements so there is no need to duplicate code for both methods.

Comment: Thank you. At least better than my version, but maybe there are even better solutions for it. I just wanna wait some minutes. Btw.: I have some elements that aren't buttons (span's etc..). Will that work for it?

Comment: Span elements don't have the disabled attribute so it won't work for them. If the Span element is acting as a button then why not use a button?

Comment: That are things I should have thought about some month ago. Refactoring would take to long for my code. Im sorry. Btw.: If you think of an icon... for me as a button, that wouldn't make sense, despite it would work.

Comment: Check the updated answer for the spans and other elements which don't allow the disabled attribute.